# RabbitMQ pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I tried to send message and receive message using RabbitMQ. I dont have computer science background, the terms I used could not be very accurate.

I try to copy the tutorial file:
When submitting my html form, my python script (cgi) the message is submitting to the queue

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)
        message = PN
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                              routing_key='task_queue',
                              body=message,
                              properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                 delivery_mode = 2, # make message persistent
                              ))
        connection.close()
```

my receiver is running :

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='task_queue', durable=True)
print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received Project %r" % body)
    #ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag) 
    if not (os.path.isfile(js_path)):
        print (' [*] ERROR files missing ')
        #ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag = method.delivery_tag)
        return
    p= subprocess.Popen(run a subprocess here)
    p.wait()

    print (' [*] Temporary Files removed')
    print(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C")

channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
channel.basic_consume(callback,queue='task_queue',no_ack=True)
channel.start_consuming()
```

It manages most of the time but randomly crash with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "Receive5.py", line 139, in <module>
    channel.start_consuming()   
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 1681, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=None)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 647, in process_data_events
    self._flush_output(common_terminator)
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 426, in _flush_output
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed() pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Comment: you should check the logs, for some reason the connection is closed on the consumer

Comment: looks to be a "heartbeat" problem..¨=ERROR REPORT==== 20-May-2016::08:36:28 ===
closing AMQP connection ...
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s

=INFO REPORT==== 20-May-2016::08:40:22 ===
accepting AMQP connection ...

=INFO REPORT==== 20-May-2016::08:44:51 ===
accepting AMQP connection ...

=INFO REPORT==== 20-May-2016::08:44:51 ===
closing AMQP connection ...

=ERROR REPORT==== 20-May-2016::08:46:22 ===
closing AMQP connection ...
missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s

=INFO REPORT==== 20-May-2016::09:38:51 ===
accepting AMQP connection ...

Comment: issue solved by setting the heartbeats to 0 ...

Comment: it been almost two years, I don't think this issue has been handled or documented better :(

Answer (score 17):

This is because you are keeping the main thread waiting, and because of this pika cannot handle incoming messages; in this case it cannot respond to the heartbeat until the subprocess is done. This causes RabbitMQ to think that the client is dead and forces a disconnection.

If you want this to work with heartbeats (which is recommend) you need to periodically call `connection.process_data_events`. This can be done by adding a loop that checks if the thread is done, and every 30s or so call `process_data_events` until the thread is done.

Comment: just curious, is the RabbitMQ tutorial missing this part or a bad use of the tutorial from my side? (https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html)

Comment: I would say that this is largely undocumented. I went as far as creating my own AMQP library to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Here is pika document about how to avoid the connection being dropped because of heartbeat.

https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/heartbeat_and_blocked_timeouts.html

In a version of pika older than 0.11.2, although we can add an argument inside the pika.ConnectionParameters: heartbeat_interval=600, but it cannot help if the server side has a short heartbeat value of 60s. It can work only when the version is at least 0.11.2

Answer (score 3):

Look add this https://github.com/mosquito/aio-pika

It's an asynchio wrapper and if u understand the concept behind asynchron very easy to use :)

Answer (score -3):

it seems that it is not connecting to RabbitMQ at 127.0.0.1:5672 -- are you sure RabbitMQ is running and listening on 127.0.0.1:5672?

### for linux (debian) users

You can check if RabbitMQ is installed by typing this command.

`sudo service rabbitmq-server status`

If you get back a response, that means it it installed. Check if it is running or not?

to start rabbitMQ serve type

`sudo service rabbitmq-server start`

to restart rabbitMq use this command

`sudo service rabbitmq-server restart`

No response means that you don't have Rabbitmq installed. install it by typing
the following commands.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get -y upgrade`

`sudo apt-get install rabbitmq-server`

And then start the server by typing the start command above.

Comment: downwoting because the answer is completely besides the point