# RabbitMQ pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed and ChannelClosed heartbeats

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I have a RabbitMQ `pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed` exception popping up sporadically and I already looked at various sources, including [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321089/rabbitmq-pika-exceptions-connectionclosed).

Where it says to use heartbeats set to 0 and use `connection.process_data_events` in a loop that I use in my code but still get the exception.

Here is the exception:

> File "/home/developer5/testfiles/dreamlead/text_cleaner/rpc_client.py", line 50, in call
> body=str(body))
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2077, in basic_publish
> mandatory, immediate)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2164, in publish
> self._flush_output()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1250, in _flush_output
> *waiters)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 474, in _flush_output
> result.reason_text)
> pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed: (-1, "ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')")

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "app.py", line 120, in handle_delivery
> registry_text = text_rpc_client.call(rpc_request_body)
> File "/home/developer5/testfiles/dreamlead/text_cleaner/rpc_client.py", line 67, in call
> self.channel.close()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1426, in close
> self._cancel_all_consumers()
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1389, in _cancel_all_consumers
> self.basic_cancel(consumer_tag)
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1675, in basic_cancel
> consumer_tag in self._impl._consumers), consumer_tag
> AssertionError: ctag1.c0482e50664c4582be6376dd0fd1eafb

Here are the RabbitMqLogs:

> closing AMQP connection <0.12978.0> (127.0.0.1:47224 -> 127.0.0.1:5672,
> client unexpectedly closed TCP connection
> missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
> =ERROR REPORT==== 18-May-2018::17:01:40 ===
> closing AMQP connection <0.12942.0> (127.0.0.1:47214 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
> missed heartbeats from client, timeout: 60s
> =ERROR REPORT==== 18-May-2018::17:09:12 ===
> closing AMQP connection <0.12602.0> (127.0.0.1:46896 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):

Here is the code:

```py
    import pika
    import uuid
    from socket import error as SocketError
    import errno
    import traceback
    from logging_settings import app_log

    class RpcClient(object):
        def __init__(self, conf):
            credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(conf.uname, conf.password)
            parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(host=conf.host, 
            credentials=credentials, connection_attempts=1000,
            retry_delay=5,heartbeat_interval=25, socket_timeout=30000000)
            self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
            self.rpc_exchange = conf.rpc_exchange
            self.rpc_key = conf.rpc_key
            self.rpc_header_key = conf.rpc_header_key
            self.rpc_header_value = conf.rpc_header_value
        
            print('credentials: ',credentials)
            print('Connection: ', self.connection)
            print('rpc_key: ', self.rpc_header_key)
        
            self.channel = self.connection.channel()
            print('Channel: ', self.channel)
        
            result = self.channel.queue_declare(exclusive=True)
            self.callback_queue = result.method.queue
        
            self.channel.basic_consume(self.on_response, no_ack=True,
                                       queue=self.callback_queue)
            print('----------------')
        
        def on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
            if self.corr_id == props.correlation_id:
                self.response = str(body, 'utf-8')

        def call(self, body):
            try:
                self.response = None
                self.corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
                print('Call Body: ', body)
                self.channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.rpc_exchange,
                                           routing_key=self.rpc_key,
                                           properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                               reply_to=self.callback_queue,
                                               correlation_id=self.corr_id,
                                               headers={self.rpc_header_key: self.rpc_header_value}
                                           ),
                                           body=str(body))
                while self.response is None:
                    self.connection.process_data_events()
                return self.response
            # except pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed as err:
            #     print('----------Connection Closed------------')
            #     app_log.error("Connection closed error: " + traceback.format_exc())
            #     time.sleep(1)
            #     continue
            #     # raise err
            # except pika.exceptions.ChannelClosed as err:
            #     print('----------Channel Closed------------')
            #     app_log.error("Channel Closed error: " + traceback.format_exc())
            #     time.sleep(1)
            #     continue
            except:
                if self.channel is not None:
                    self.channel.close()
                if self.connection is not None:
                    self.connection.close()
```

Perhaps the problem has to do with my computer?
`ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer')`

Or the placement of `self.connection.process_data_events()` in my code?

Comment: see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have an example RPC implementation for pika here that you can use as a reference https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py

Comment: I think this has been discussed many times: the current best practice is keeping heartbeating in your connection thread, and running your business logic in a separate thread.

Comment: @Alan Abishev - did you solve this?

Comment: Sorry, it was so long ago, I can't remember if I solved the problem or not