# python pika rabbitmq exeception what is cause of exception

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

```
import pika,traceback
import xyz
import time
from datetime import datetime
import ast
import error_mail

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('xxxxx', 'xxxxxx')
parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters('xxxxxxxxx', 5672,         '/',credentials,blocked_connection_timeout=400,heartbeat=600)
connection=pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='xxxxxxxx')
def callback(ch, method, properties,body):
  try:
    print("*****data******")
    print ("TIMESTAMP[#] {}".format(datetime.now()))
    print(body)
    xyz.yyy(body)
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
  except Exception as e:
    error = traceback.format_exc()
    print(error)
    error_mail.sent_Mail(error)
channel.basic_consume(
queue='xxxxxxxx', on_message_callback=callback)
print('Waiting for messages')
channel.start_consuming()
```

ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 2103, in basic_ack
self._impl.basic_ack(delivery_tag=delivery_tag, multiple=multiple)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/channel.py", line 202, in basic_ack
self._raise_if_not_open()
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pika/channel.py", line 1389, in _raise_if_not_open
raise exceptions.ChannelWrongStateError('Channel is closed.')
ChannelWrongStateError: Channel is closed.

Comment: Hello Sharad, please provide your code. This way we will be able to help you

Comment: Hi Guillem , im update my code in the question

Comment: Providing some context or explaining the requirement would help us understand the question better.

Comment: Also providing the publisher code would be good

Comment: issue is years long and still not addressed ! https://github.com/pika/pika/issues/1240 ...moving to Kombu...

Answer (score 2):

From here: [RabbitMQ pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37321089/rabbitmq-pika-exceptions-connectionclosed)

> This is because you are keeping the main thread waiting, and because of this pika cannot handle incoming messages; in this case it cannot respond to the heartbeat until the subprocess is done. This causes RabbitMQ to think that the client is dead and forces a disconnection.
> If you want this to work with heartbeats (which is recommend) you need to periodically call connection.process_data_events. This can be done by adding a loop that checks if the thread is done, and every 30s or so call process_data_events until the thread is done.

Try without heartbeat such in the hello world example: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html